# Oracle EDITIONABLE property error while import backup from 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have oracle 11G dump files. When i import it to 12.2.0.1.0 it is imported as expected. After that i need to run my latest DDL script which contains CREATE OR REPLACE View/Function/Procedure/Type. When i execute my script i am getting below error.

```
ORA-38824: A CREATE OR REPLACE command may not change the EDITIONABLE property of an existing object.
```

After importing dump file when i saw user_objects data all my imported objects have EDITIONABLE = N. Do i need to change default value before importing by dump file? I need to fix this with minimum steps. Client(s) wont execute complex scripts or wont give complex permissions. I tried below statement but not works.

```
alter user pjs enable editions;
```

Comment: Have you imported your dump in one of the PDBs?

Comment: I am not aware about PDB. we will export each release data in  DMP files and use them when ever it needs.

Answer (score 2):

This relates to [Edition-Based Redefinition](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/high-availability/ebr.html). From 12c, you can mark individual objects as `(non)editionable`. The default is `editionable`.

As the error implies, you can't change this property when using `create or replace`.

The import must have created the objects as `noneditionable`. So you have a few options:

- Add the `noneditionable` keyword in your scripts
- Alter the objects to be `editionable` - if the user is *not* editions enabled
- Drop all noneditionable objects and re-create them

For example:

```
create or replace noneditionable procedure prc ( p int ) as
begin
  null;
end prc;
/

select editionable 
from   user_objects
where  object_name = 'PRC';

EDITIONABLE   
N  

alter procedure prc editionable;

select editionable 
from   user_objects
where  object_name = 'PRC';

EDITIONABLE   
Y     

grant create session, 
      create procedure 
  to u 
  identified by u;

alter user u enable editions;

conn u/u

create or replace noneditionable procedure prc ( p int ) as
begin
  null;
end prc;
/

select editionable 
from   user_objects
where  object_name = 'PRC';

EDITIONABLE   
N   

create or replace procedure prc ( p int ) as
begin
  null;
end prc;
/

ORA-38824: A CREATE OR REPLACE command may not change the EDITIONABLE property of an existing object.

alter procedure prc editionable;

ORA-38825: The EDITIONABLE property of an editioned object cannot be altered.

select editionable 
from   user_objects
where  object_name = 'PRC';

EDITIONABLE   
N   

drop procedure prc;

create or replace procedure prc ( p int ) as
begin
  null;
end prc;
/

select editionable 
from   user_objects
where  object_name = 'PRC';

EDITIONABLE   
Y
```

Comment: I am not able to drop my objects. Can i alter object and add editionable? Actually i tried and working now. Can i do that will i get any problem in feature?

Comment: You can - but only if the user is **not** `editions enabled`; I've updated the answer with details